# Is it possible to draw multiple contour in an image

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I have an image which has three classes. Each class is labelled by number `{2,3,4}` and background is `{1}`. I want to draw contours of each class in an image. I tried the MATLAB code below, but the contours look overlap together (blue and green, yellow and green). How can I draw a contour per class?

```
Img=ones(128,128);
Img(20:end-20,20:end-20)=2;
Img(30:end-30,30:end-30)=3;
Img(50:end-50,50:end-50)=4;
%%Img(60:end-60,60:end-60)=3; %% Add one more rectangular
imagesc(Img);colormap(gray);hold on; axis off;axis equal;
[c2,h2] = contour(Img==2,[0 1],'g','LineWidth',2);
[c3,h3] = contour(Img==3,[0 1],'b','LineWidth',2);
[c4,h4] = contour(Img==4,[0 1],'y','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
```

[image]

This is my expected result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because each "class" is defined as a hollow square in terms of its shape.  Therefore, when you use `contour` it traces over all boundaries of the square.  Take for example just one class when you plot this on the figure.  Specifically, take a look at your first binary image you create with `Img == 2`.  We get this image:

[image]

Therefore, if you called `contour` on this shape, you'd actually be tracing the boundaries of this object.  It makes more sense now doesn't it?  If you repeated this for the rest of your classes, this is the reason why the contour lines are overlapping in colour.  The innermost part of the hollow square is overlapping with the outermost part of another square.  Now when you call `contour` the first time you actually will get this:

[image]

As you can see, "class 2" is actually defined to be the hollowed out grey square.  If you want to achieve what you desire, one way is to **fill in** each hollow square then apply `contour` to this result.  Assuming you have the image processing toolbox, use [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) with the `'holes'` option at each step:

```
Img=ones(128,128);
Img(20:end-20,20:end-20)=2;
Img(50:end-50,50:end-50)=3;
Img(30:end-30,30:end-30)=3;
Img(35:end-35,35:end-35)=3;
Img(50:end-50,50:end-50)=4;
imagesc(Img);colormap(gray);hold on; axis off;axis equal;

%// New
%// Create binary mask with class 2 and fill in the holes
im = Img == 2;
im = imfill(im, 'holes');
%// Now draw contour
[c2,h2] = contour(im,[0 1],'g','LineWidth',2);

%// Repeat for the rest of the classes
im = Img == 3;
im = imfill(im, 'holes');

[c3,h3] = contour(im,[0 1],'b','LineWidth',2);
im = Img == 4;
im = imfill(im, 'holes');

[c4,h4] = contour(im,[0 1],'y','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
```

We now get this:

[image]

Comment: I tested your method. It has one issue. If I create an small rectangular as Img(60:end-60,60:end-60)=3; then your code does not draw it. Please update the code to create the Img in my question

Comment: Of course it doesn't.  You are merging two regions together into a single class.  The code will naturally not draw it.  There's nothing to update as you are specifying an impossible situation.

Comment: Please look at figure 8 in this paper http://www.unc.edu/~liwa/neonatal%20brain%20image%20segmentation.pdf . He can draws contour for merging regions.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Sorry. Please let explain my question again. I have multiple classes. I want to draw contour for each class, so that each contour has different color.

Comment: As the figure 8 in the reference paper, it has three class. Each class is drawn by red and blue colors.

Comment: @user8264 I'll have a look and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Do you free time? Could you look at the paper and let me know if it is possible way?